# Fix for Windows Mixed Reality Portal Installation via Microsoft Store Leading to "Something Went Wrong" Error

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-mixed-reality

I've had to deal with another MS nonsensical issue when I couldnt install their worthless WMR portal through the MS store. Luckily its possible to run Powershell commands to install it manually.

You can use similar commands to install and uninstall other apps if the MS store misbehaves provided you know the name for those apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install:

```
Get-AppXPackage *Microsoft.MixedReality.Portal* -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

To Uninstall:

```
Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.MixedReality.Portal | Remove-AppxPackage
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that doing an in-place upgrade worked for me, but this might've been a better approch, although if this error message appeared then there's probably something wrong with your windows installation or registry anyway, so an in-place upgrade may still be the way to go.

Comment: You could be right about something being wrong with my windows. I have not bought the OS, I use their free version on MS's website that comes with no customization and a water mark.